# Adding panel again after removing it from DOM fails

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs, panel, render, extjs4.1

I create a panel with:

```
oMainView = Ext.create('My.panel.view');
```

I store `oMainView` to an object to add this panel again later!

Then I add `oMainView` to my DOM via `add()`:

```
// Div to put it in
var oWindowDiv = Ext.get( strStartDiv );
// Container to hold it
var oContainer = Ext.create( 'Ext.container.Container', {
         id        : 'findMe',
         layout    : 'fit',
         renderTo  : oWindowDiv,
         autoRender: true
      });
oContainer.add(oMainView);
```

Later then, our framework deletes all these Divs on minimizing. No page refresh. So on maximize I want to add `oMainView`, which I have stored, in the same manner.

This works perfectly in FF and Chrome. But Internet Explorer (7, 8, 9) fails to render the panel. It only renders the empty HTML element.

What is the problem?

PS. I dont want to re-create the panel! Just adding again to the container.

---

Edit: The problem must be with the created panel object. Because adding a fresh test panel works:

```
oTest = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
               title: 'Test',
               html: 'Text'
            });
```

But adding this stored up panel does not work, there is also no error. The Div just stays empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days now finally the solution:

Right before the Ext container gets removed from DOM, I needed to call `.removeAll(false);`.

Comment: could you please post the code how you achieved "Right before the Ext container gets removed from DOM, I needed to call .removeAll(false);" ? I am facing the same problem with EXTJS 4.1 with IE8.
Appreciate your help. Edit - btw, sorry for posting here, but I dont have enough reps for commenting :(

Comment: I catch the event from our framework before the containers get removed. Then on this `Ext.container.Container` I call `myContainer.removeAll(false);` You need to find the point where your containers get removed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the ExtJS components are supposed to work/to be used. And notice that the rendering & layouting is the heavy part of a component creation and that need to be done every time in your case. I would recommend to to hide unused components, if you really don't want to destroy them. You could archive this easy with a card layout.

But back to your Problem; The component will store private params which indicate if it has already been rendered, that may cause problems sometimes. You should also remove a child-component from the DOM (hopefully resetting it's internal params) by the use of [remove()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-remove)  called from the owner container with the `autoDestroy: false` setting.

Check also that you don't have duplicate id's!

By the way using `renderTo: oWindowDiv` along with `autoRender: true` doens't make sense. In your case the second config does nothing cause you have already a render target into which the container get's rendered.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot hide nor remove anything, since Extjs is used within another JS framework, which removes all ExtJs DOM elements on minimize, but my Extjs objects stay. I am forced to re-add it. And re-creating it would not have the effect of maximizing. Since it works in FF and Chrome, why not IE? I will check the internal params and ids.

Comment: Did not fix it. What else could I try?

Comment: @Idianer I guess you can't do much. You can still try calling doLayout() by yourself but I doubt that will solve your problem. You will have to debug the add process an see what goes wrong there.